# Is there any Castle ActiveRecord generator from Visual Studio 2010 Modeling Project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-generation, uml, castle-activerecord

Visual Studio 2010 includes a Modeling Project that lets to create UML diagrams like class diagram. We have plenty of class diagrams in VS 2010 Modeling Project and wish to generate Castle ActiveRecord classes from them.

I have searched and found many tools like [ActiveWriter](http://using.castleproject.org/display/Contrib/ActiveWriter), [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx), [Active-Record-Gen](http://roytate.blogspot.com/2007/07/castle-active-record-code-generator.html), [The DarkSide](http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2008/10/30/generator-studio-released-on-codeplex.aspx), [GeneratorStudio](http://generatorstudio.codeplex.com/) and [The AgilityForORMs Castle ActiveRecord code generator](http://www.agilityfororms.com/Home/Products/). But all of them generate classes from database only not VS 2010 Modeling Projects or UML XMI.

Do you know any tool for generating Castle ActiveRecord classes from VS 2010 Modeling Project's class diagrams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible. Maybe instead of generating Castle AR models based on your UML diagram you can generate your database from your UML and then use one of the tools you listed to reverse engineer it?

[This](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/01/uml-modeling-and-code-generation-in-visual-studio-2010/) link appears to generate the DDL which you could then use.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write your own templates. 
Search on "How to Generate Files from a UML Model" and "How to Generate Code from UML Classes".